# Stop auto-correcting date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

There is an auto-correct when a wrong date is entered by hand in the input. (Ex : typing 32/3/2017 will be converted to 01/04/2017). whiteout informing to user.

I would like to turn this feature off,I want when user input invalid date,date picker should be clear when he leave date time picker.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

option : forceParse to false

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#forceparse

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) then use `keepInvalid : true`

And if you are working with [DateTime Picker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) then use `forceParse : false`